# What does double colons and underscore mean in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I am learning basic PHP, trying to read and get some basic understanding of JOOMLA core files, whereas I come across a lot of operators like "::_", which I don't understand.

I did some google research and there are a lot of explanations regarding double colons (::), but almost nothing on "::_", one of the files that contain this operator is joomla-site-root/mod_login/tmpl/default.php, and the line is

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php', true, $params->get('usesecure')); ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
```

So what does this mean? Is "JRoute::_('index.php', true, $params->get('usesecure'))" a function call of class JRoute? if yes, what function is it? I checked out the joomla API(http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Application/JRouter.html) but still remain clueless. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `::` is a scope resolution operator. It is calling the static function `_` on the JRoute object. http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JRoute

Comment: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/application/route.php Line 42 is the function that is called from this string.

Answer (score 4):

The :: as mentioned is the [scope resolution operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), it allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties. So, in Joomla's case and your question it's accessing a class static method called '_'.

The underscore '_' is actually the name of the method.

In Joomla you will find lots of classes implement underscore methods, e.g. the default text translation utility:

```
echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_SORT_BTN_LABEL');  // This is the most commonly used one.
```

Only a few though still use static functions. `JHTML` is an example where `[JHTML::_][2]` acts like a class loader, loading helper file based on the first parameter passed in as the `$key`

```
echo JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
echo JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
echo JHtml::_('sliders.panel', JText::_($fieldset->label), $fieldset->name);
echo JHtml::_('link', JHelp::createUrl('JHELP_GLOSSARY'), JText::_('COM_ADMIN_GLOSSARY'), array('target' => 'helpFrame'));
```

`JLanguage` is a Joomla class with an underscore method that you may see used around the place but unlike [`JRoute`](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/JRoute.html), `[JText][4]` or `[JHTML][5]` it's not called statically. e.g.

```
$lang = JLanguage::getInstance($toUser->getParam('admin_language', $default_language), $debug);
$lang->load('com_messages', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
$subject = sprintf ($lang->_('COM_MESSAGES_NEW_MESSAGE_ARRIVED'), $sitename);
```

Answer (score 0):

The double colon is called the [scope resolution operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) and is used for calling static class methods or properties. Underscore doesnt mean anything but `_()` is usually used for string translations.

Answer (score 0):

the double colon is used with OOP (object oriented programming). If you're new to programming in general, objects are really useful with reusing code and definitely worth looking into once you're more comfortable with programming in general... that is if you aren't already experienced. Hope that helps!

-Frank